# Is there anything analogous to <exclusion>?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

Let's say we have a main project B which is a child of project A which contains a bunch of dependencies
Now B has a few dependencies: C, D and E.
C and D depend of F v2.0
E automatically picks up any version of F but it does not work with F v2.0 but instead needs to use F v1.0

So the hierarchy is something like this

```
    A---------
    |        |
    |        |
parent of    | 
    |  inherits dependency version
    B        |
    |        |
    ----C----F (v2.0 picked up from A)
    |        |
    ----D----F (v2.0 picked up from A)
    |        |
    ----E----F (v2.0 picked up from A)
```

But what I want is to specify a specific F dependency version for E so that instead of it picking up the version from A parent project, it uses the version I specify. It would look something like this:

```
    A---------
    |        |
    |        |
parent of    | 
    |  inherits dependency version
    B        |
    |        |
    ----C----F (v2.0 picked up from A)
    |        |
    ----D----F (v2.0 picked up from A)
    |        
    ----E----F (v1.0 specified explicitly)
```

Is there any way I can accomplish that with maven? I need this unfortunately as one of the dependencies requires an older version of the lib while all the other dependencies need to use the newer one.

Answer (score 0):

Using two versions of the same library is something one should avoid as much as possible.

You can shade one of the library versions with the Maven shade plugin, but this is the last resort. Better upgrade.

Comment: Unfortunately Lib E is not under my control so I cannot update it, also I don't think I can shade the lib I don't have control over.